# Blocking Sites from opening new Sites

Tags: google-chrome, popups

There are certain websites that open new windows (this kind of new window is without bookmarks, etc., I don't know what they are called - don't know if that's still called Popups because they are like a normal website).

Is there any Chrome Addon to block this kind of behavior? 
A Whitelist-Function would be appreciated.

I don't know if this is the right board for this kind of questions, I'm sorry if its not.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SuperUser! This website is not for software recommendation, so you may want to refine your question in order to make it fit with our topic guidelines: https://superuser.com/help/on-topic
Prefer asking "How can I do..." rather than "What can I use to ...".

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pop-up-blocker-for-chrome/bkkbcggnhapdmkeljlodobbkopceiche?hl=en) recently. Lets you allow popups for specific websites.